Centering a displayed equation in an enumerate environment
I am using a template which somehow changes the spacing of a displaystyle equation inside an enumerate environment, so it is centered with respect to the full page, instead of the text in the particular item:

Is there any way I could change this locally for this particular list? For context, I have the enumitem package loaded, and I tried messing around with the spacings, for example, setting leftmargin to 0, but that just puts the labels out of place. I could also put the template code, but it is too long (~350 lines).
Edit. The template I am using is Graduate Studies in Mathematics from the AMS Monographs dropdown at the AMS website. Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\]
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


I guess that the template is based on amsart or amsbook. But without a full compilable example it's impossible to help. If my guess is correct, doing \let\fullwidthdisplay\relax may solve the issue.

@egreg: Thank you, it worked! (Your guess is correct, the template is taken from the AMS website.) You could post that as an answer.

Not if you don't complete the question.

@egreg: Edited the post.

@ultralegend5385 Added an answer. Read carefully the final comment.

The classes available from AMS are all based either on amsart or amsbook.
If we look at the value of \everydisplay in such classes, we see
\fullwidthdisplay\@displaytrue

When only amsmath is loaded, the value of \everydisplay is just
\@displaytrue

What's \fulldisplaywidth? In those classes it is
\displayindent=0pt \displaywidth=\columnwidth

In most classes, \displayindent (whose meaning should be clear) is not set, so TeX computes it based on the context. In the case of lists, the display indent is the same as \@totalleftmargin (it's a bit long to explain the reason which has to do with \parshape), so displays are centered with respect to the list.
If you want to keep the standard typesetting, you can just make \fullwidthdisplay a no-op.
\documentclass{amsbook} % the same for gsm-l
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% remove the action of \fullwidthdisplay
\let\fullwidthdisplay\relax

\begin{document}

\[
  1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\]

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
  \[
    1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
  \]
  \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Without the \let instruction you'd get

Comment Don't monkey with classes you're required to use. You know how to achieve your objective, but don't do it.

Thanks, I am not required to use the class, as I am doing for my personal use. (I just needed a good-looking template to typeset my notes.)
